# DRC robot falls when rotating in place

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

*Extracted from [question 2665](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/2665)*

When executing certain movement based commands, the atlas robot does not perform the same action any two times in a row even though it has been specifically told to perform the same thing it just did last simulation. For example, if you tell atlas to turn by x degrees, and then stand still, atlas might do the following:

- Trial 1) Actually Turn X degrees and Successfully Stand Still
- Trial 2) Actually Turn X degrees and fall to the right
- Trial 3) Actually Turn X degrees and fall forward
- Trial 4) Turn Y Degrees and fall backward
- Trial 5) Turn Y Degrees and fall to the left

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2722/drc-robot-falls-when-rotating-in-place/) by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I assume that you're using the keyboard teleop tool described in [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.5/keyboard_teleop).  As noted in the [Known Issues section](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.5/keyboard_teleop#Known_Issues), in-place rotation as implemented in the keyboard teleop tool is [unstable](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/205/atlas-falls-while-rotating-in-place-using).

That problem will be resolved eventually, but the keyboard teleop tool is meant primarily as an example to show you how to write your own control code, so we're not spending much time on making it robust.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2013-05-10**:
Thank you.